# How to display everything wrong with input for password tester

Tags: python, python-module

My program works perfectly fine but instead of returning EVERYTHING wrong with a password it will only return one problem back.

Example:
The password is ASD123 (the problems being less than 10 characters, and no symbols). The program only returns "The password is less than 10 characters"

```
passwordisokk = True

def passwordisOK():
    while True:
        passwordisokk = input("Please enter a password so we can validate:")
        if len(passwordisokk) < 10:
            print(" Your password should be 10 characters,please enter more characters")
            passwordisokk = False
            print(passwordisokk)
        elif re.search("[0-9]",passwordisokk) is None:
            print("Your password needs a number,please enter one")
            passwordisokk = False
            print(passwordisokk)
        elif re.search("[A-Z]",passwordisokk) is None:
            print(" Your password needs a capital letter,please enter one")
            passwordisokk = False
            print(passwordisokk)
        elif re.search("[$,#,%,&,*]",passwordisokk) is None:
            print(" You password needs one of these symbols:$,#,%,&,*. Please enter one")
            passwordisokk = False
            print(passwordisokk)
        elif re.search("[ ]",passwordisokk):
            passwordisokk = False
            print("No spaces when entering your password please")
            print(passwordisokk)
        else:
            passwordisokk = True
            print(passwordisokk)
            break
passwordisOK()
```

Comment: change the `elif`s to `if`s and then the final `else` should be `if not passwordisokk:`

Comment: I have tried that but when I try running it with an invalid password, the program will go out and say error

Comment: Please update your code with an example of an invalid password input and the full traceback of the error.

Comment: "error" is not a problem description.  We need to know what went wrong -- follow the posting standards you used the first time.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/iKi4wGh.png

Comment: @stampgod You're overwriting your variable `passwordisokk`... Check my answer

Comment: https://imgur.com/eeU4iFR I copy and pasted it and tried entering a invalid password but an error still showed up

Comment: @stampgod `import re`, I've updated my code.

Comment: @moritzg https://imgur.com/bnYZWhx Thanks man, I had to remove the if not at the end because the program would break and print True so I changed it just to an else and now its working the I want it to , thanks man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the `elif` and `else` to `if` statements.

```
import re

passwordisokk = True

def checkPasswordisOK():
    while True:
        password = input("Please enter a password so we can validate:")
        if len(password) < 10:
            print(" Your password should be 10 characters,please enter more characters")
            passwordisokk = False
            print(passwordisokk)
        if re.search("[0-9]",password) is None:
            print("Your password needs a number,please enter one")
            passwordisokk = False
            print(passwordisokk)
        if re.search("[A-Z]",password) is None:
            print(" Your password needs a capital letter,please enter one")
            passwordisokk = False
            print(passwordisokk)
        if re.search("[$,#,%,&,*]",password) is None:
            print(" You password needs one of these symbols:$,#,%,&,*. Please enter one")
            passwordisokk = False
            print(passwordisokk)
        if re.search("[ ]",password):
            passwordisokk = False
            print("No spaces when entering your password please")
            print(passwordisokk)
        if not passwordisokk:
            passwordisokk = True
            print(passwordisokk)
            break
checkPasswordisOK()
```

Comment: I tried that but when I change the else to an if it says invalid syntax